# Hosting legacy Silverlight application in an ASP.NET MVC3 web application

Tags: silverlight, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to convert an existing silverlight application to use a MVC web application versus a regular asp.net web application.

I have taken a look at fiddler and it is not able to access the domain service methods as the service does not exist (this is because these files are autogenerated once they are called with ria services). But with MVC since it looks for the controller if files don't physically exist we are getting this error.

I have tried to ignore svc files by:
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allsvc}", new { allsvc = @".*.svc(/.*)?" });

and also have tried;
http://xamlcoder.com/blog/2010/01/15/upgrading-to-wcf-ria-services-asp-net-mvc-2/

With no success. Has anyone been able to successfully do this, if so, how?

Thanks in advance.